# SQLi Select Variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I have hopefully a simple question.

Currently I have a piece of code which works and behaves really well.

```
    $db = new SafeMySQL();
    $items = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM imagedirectory WHERE menuid=?i and imageid=?i",9999,3);
    echo drawImageList($items);
```

What I would like to do is make an adjustment to this code to set the 'menuid' and 'imageid as a variable.

e.g.

```
$displaymenuid = "9999";
$displayimageid = 3";


        $db = new SafeMySQL();
        $items = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM imagedirectory WHERE menuid=?i and imageid=?i",$displaymenuid,$displayimageid);
```

I am relatively new to SQLi so I am struggling to find the right syntax to make the above work.
        echo drawImageList($items);

Comment: $displayimageid = "3";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,you missing double quote in your $displayimageid variable.

```
$displaymenuid = "9999";
$displayimageid = "3";

$db = new SafeMySQL();
$items = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM imagedirectory WHERE menuid=?i and imageid=?i",$displaymenuid,$displayimageid);
```

Comment: Cheers, Somedays are just better than others!

Comment: @Brandrally,Glad !I could help to resolve your issue.